# Laravel 10, Vite 4, Vue 3, Homestead getting 404 when npm run dev - is it compatibility issue

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vite, homestead

I am new to vuejs, I have successfully initiated a laravel 10 app with vite 4 and vue 3 in my homestead environment. However,

I have problems when i try to do

```
 npm run dev
```

it just stops working and i get 404 errors on @vite client and other files.

however, when i just build it and run it

```
 npm run build
```

it works fine and i can see the content on my components.

the people i have found while googling on this said that homestead is not compatible with vue3, can someone please confirm?

i have these setup for my environment already

1. ssl enabled for homestead sites
2. port 5173 added in my homestead yaml file
3. ssl, port 5173 explicitly declared in my vite config
4. custom url defined as well local.webapp.test

does anybody have any idea what i am doing wrong?